# Driver issue with Wireless on Lenovo T61P

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, thinkpad

Im trying to reinstall the wireless driver on a User's laptop. I have the right Intel driver from the Lenovo sight. But everytime I select the driver for it to download I get an error message at the end saying.

"The i/o operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request driver"

And then the driver is not installed so the user cant use wifi. Im looking for something I can do remotely since this user is in Germany and Im in Canada.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran DriveCleaner and used the clean driver.cab utility  within the program. Then I proceeded to uninstall the wireless software and drivers and then rebooted and reinstalled them and they worked.